# Java Pubnub Subscribing to Channel

Tags: java, android, pubnub

I am new to Pubnub and i was just needing some help with my code:

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.pubnub.api.*;
import org.json.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("Tag", "Start");
    final Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("demo", "demo");
    Log.i("Tag", "Creation of pubnub");

    try{
        pubnub.subscribe("DavidsChannel", new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:" + channel
                                + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                                + message.toString());
                        Log.i("Tag", "CONNECT");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
                                + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                                + message.toString());
                        Log.i("Tag", "DISCONNECT");
                    }

                    public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
                                + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                                + message.toString());
                        Log.i("Tag", "RECONNECT");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                                + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
                        Log.i("Tag", channel);
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel
                                + " : " + error.toString());
                        Log.i("Tag", "ERROR");
                    }
                }
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + " : " + e.toString());
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I doesn't subscribe to the channel and returns:

08-14 10:47:06.625  13752-13752/? I/Tag﹕ Start

08-14 10:47:06.641  13752-13752/? I/Tag﹕ Creation of pubnub

08-14 10:47:06.655  13752-13773/? I/Tag﹕ ERROR

I was also getting this error:

08-14 10:42:06.321    2828-2856/? W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕untagSocket(52) failed with errno -22

Please help me, Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should learn how to debug ... obviously first step is .... to add some error info  instead loggin' useless "Tag: ERROR" ... next step would be to learn how to use breakpoints

Comment: Ok thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/pubnub/java
Just copy and remove extra stuff. Create new basic project then move their project files across accordingly.